# Hide navigation bar in all the views, swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Currently I am working on SwiftUI project. I want to hide the build-in navbar. For this purpose I have to add these lines,

```
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

to each of view before pushing it into navigation controller in SwiftUI.

```
   NavigationLink(destination:
                    ForgotPasswordView()
                              .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                              .navigationBarHidden(true)
    
    ) {
            Text("Forgot Password?")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
```

Same will be done for LoginView

```
NavigationLink(destination:
                        LoginView()
                                  .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                                  .navigationBarHidden(true)
        
        ) {
                Text("Login")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
```

So I need any generic method like we did in storyboard, hide it from root view and no child will have the navbar on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **custom modifier** to **hide** the **navigation bar** like this:

```
struct HideNavBar : ViewModifier {
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

extension View {
    var hideNavigationBar: some View {
        modifier(HideNavBar())
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination:
                    ForgotPasswordView()
                              .hideNavigationBar
    
    ) {
            Text("Forgot Password?")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Updated for iOS 16+

You can wrap the view by creating a new view that accepts a child view, which adds all the necessary modifiers so that you don't have to repeat it every time.

```swift
struct NavigationWrapper<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var childView: Content
    
    var body: some View {
        childView
            .toolbar(.hidden)
    }
}
```

Now, you can use that wrapper for your navigation link's destination.

Here is an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                    NavigationLink("Row \(i)") {
                        NavigationWrapper {
                            Text("Detailed view for \(i)th row.")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            .navigationTitle("RowGap")
            .toolbar(.hidden)
        }
    }
}
```

It hides out the navigation bar and toolbar completely.